# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," in react.js

Tags: java, reactjs, syntax-error

**I write This code in react.js**

```
  function Sidebar() {
        const [rooms, setRooms] = useState( [] );
        useEffect(() => {
            db.collection("rooms").onSnapshot((snapshot)
            =>
            setRooms(
                snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    data: doc.data(),
    
                })
                ))
            );
        }, []);
```

**And it shows error:**

./src/Sidebar.js
Line 17:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```
  15 |     useEffect(() => {
  16 |         db.collection("rooms").onSnapshot((snapshot)
> 17 |         =>
     |         ^
  18 |         setRooms(
  19 |             snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
  20 |                 id: doc.id,
```

Comment: This is my first question in stackoverflow that's why sorry for confusing

Comment: i think becaus `=>` its in the next line. try move it right after snapshot `onSnapshot((snapshot) =>`

Comment: OMG you are great .. Problem fixed

Comment: Please remove the java tag. Java has nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As Luis pointed out in comment moving `=>` right after `(snapshot)` will solve the issue. Just to add use some kind of IDE. [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is recommended IDE for React development) but you can use any other IDE and setup eslint, prettier and autoformatonsave options so that you don't have to spend too much time in fixing these type of issues. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHAeK8t94as) is great tutorial to setup VSCode with all extensions.